# Doctrine Get Entities Based on Selected Category Children

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want to get records related with selected category's children.

For example, we have a category tree like this:

Main:

1. Fruit
2. Car

Children: (Parent Id can not be empty! In this example: Parent Id = 1)

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Banana

And we have an entity (db record) like this:

```
id = 1, category_id = 2, title = This records must belong to ORANGE category!
```

When we select the Fruit category from the database, i must get entites related with Fruit itself and it's children categories.

What i'v tried?

```
$qb
->select('i.id, i.title, i.slug, i.created_at, c.file')
->from('CSImageBundle:Image', 'i')
->leftJoin('i.taxonomies', 'tx')
->leftJoin('tx.children', 'st')
->where($qb->expr()->in('tx.id', 'st.id'));
```

Fails...

What should i try?

Comment: How does it fails?, can you provide the error or exception message, also can you provide your mappings for main and childrens. Are those different entities or do children reference its parent on the same entity?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without an error message, but it looks like an issue in your select, where is c.file?

```
$qb
->select('i.id, i.title, i.slug, i.created_at, c.file') //should this be i.file? or tx.file? or st.file?
->from('CSImageBundle:Image', 'i')
->leftJoin('i.taxonomies', 'tx')
->leftJoin('tx.children', 'st')
->where($qb->expr()->in('tx.id', 'st.id'));
```